# Difference between haversine formula & geodesic distance for calculating distance

Tags: python, distance, geodesic, geopy, haversine

## Background

I have Vehicle driving data which includes Lat/Long points of a particular route. I drive in that route for 2 times. 
The driving data in that route is around 20 minutes. (Approximately for 2 times = 40 mins)

## Distance Calculation

Before I have been using haversine formula to calculate distance between every point between route 1 & route 2.
recently I came across geopy library which uses geodesic distance function to calculate distance.

## Question/Requirement

So my question is, which one produces better results either haversine  or geodesic distance?

Comment: Surely you can evaluate this for yourself. Spherical calculations on a spheroidal object are intrinsically inaccurate but fast. Geodesic calculations are accurate but slow. *Too* inaccurate vice *too* slow is a value judgement we can't make for you.

Comment: Could you elaborate or post some links, i cannot understand ..@Vince

Comment: A similar question (by someone else) was [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38248046/is-the-haversine-formula-or-the-vincentys-formula-better-for-calculating-distan) in 2016 on StackOverflow.